# dimple chart color change not working

Tags: jquery, html, colors, dimple.js

can you help me with my problem pls?
I'm currently on this contrinents/country graph:
http://jsbin.com/yigomu/1/edit?html,js,output

I would like to know why it's not showing the color change on this example:
1 bar blue, 1 bar red, then again 1 bar blue, 1 bar red and so on.
http://jsfiddle.net/uafGn/

Even if the settings for the dimple chart are the same.

```
x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Fruit", "Year"]);
x.addGroupOrderRule([2012, 2013]);
```

I tried everything, it's just not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimple colours by the last field specified in the addSeries function.  So you just need to include the dimension you want to colour by there:

```
myChart.addSeries("Point", dimple.plot.bar);
```

becomes:

```
myChart.addSeries(["Point", "Year"], dimple.plot.bar);
```

EDIT:

Actually looking at your example there is no need for "Point" in the series.  It should just be:

```
myChart.addSeries("Year", dimple.plot.bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the charts colors like this.

```
chart.defaultColors = [
    new dimple.color("red"),
    new dimple.color("blue"),
];
```

Comment: that doesn't solve my issue http://jsbin.com/yigomu/12/edit?html,js,output. What i need is one bar blue, one bar red, then again one bar blue, one bar red and so on